# Does blender offer a posterization option for rendering?

Tags: rendering, effects

For example zbrush has the following option:

http://docs.pixologic.com/user-guide/materials-lights-rendering/posterization/

Maya has vector renderer which create a comic like poster effect. Does blender's option for posterization work with animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not as such, no. But there is a toon shader for Blender Internal, and some similar results have been developed for Cycles.

What is probably more useful to you is a compositing setup that will operate on the render, rather than the material. Some success has been had with [this](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?244118-Cool-nodes-I-didn-t-know-about) node setup, using the "Round" algorithm. It separates RGB, rounds each to the nearest 0.1, and then recombines them.

Hope that helps!